# Missing server side dependencies error

Tags: web-part, content-database, sharepoint-farm, server

> Title   Missing server side dependencies.
>
> Severity   1 - Error
>
> Category   Configuration
>
> Explanation    [MissingWebPart] WebPart class
>   [3417184e-0312-0308-7a02-a4b2ce7fa8aa] is referenced [6] times in the
>   database [WSS_Content_Test], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature/solution which contains this web part. One
>   or more web parts are referenced in the database [WSS_Content_Test],
>   but are not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature
>   or solution which contains these web parts. [MissingWebPart] WebPart
>   class [35aee725-be5b-7f5c-30f1-fb758cbc1310] is referenced [2] times
>   in the database [WSS_Content_Test], but is not installed on the
>   current farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this
>   web part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database
>   [WSS_Content_Test], but are not installed on the current farm. Please
>   install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.
>
> Remedy     For more information about this rule, see
>   "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142689".
>
> Failing Servers
>
> Failing Services    SPTimerService (SPTimerV4)

I have search the web and found many solutions but no one convinced me. looking for authentic and accurate solution? If any body have solved this issue then please share your experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically because the web part exists on a page or is in the solution gallery. Most developers do not put in feature deactivation code to clean up any instances of the web part and remove it from the web part gallery. This is why these errors come up. They need to be removed for the error to be resolved.

In a 2007 to 2010 migration, we had to go through and remove all these references because we had a lot of third party web parts that were not able to be upgraded to 2010.

Comment: Thats fine! but whats the solution to this error now...

Comment: It is either to install the feature that deployed the web parts or find and destroy the existing instances of the web part.

Comment: @SPBeginer you can follow this guide: http://get-spscripts.com/2011/08/diagnose-missingwebpart-and.html